# Why won't my images show in my HTML file?

Tags: html, image

Is there something wrong with my syntax? I have an images folder located in the same folder as the html file. Images from URLs work fine.
`<img src="images/ai_1.png" width="500" height="300"/>`

[Images folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRyzd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the directory is named `templates`…

You have some server-side (or build-time) code which takes a URL and *somehow* translates that into an instruction to generate an HTML document from that template and other stuff (probably includes and some page specific data).

The relative URL you have in the `src` attribute is computed from the URL of the generated HTML document.

The browser asks for that URL and the server can't find a suitable response for it.

The image files aren't templates so shouldn't be in the templates.

This kind of system typically has a specific directory to store static files in. The images should be in there.

You then need to specify a URL which is mapped onto that static directory by the server code.

Comment: Thanks Quentin! So I should move the images folder into the static folder and change the relative path to: <img src="../static/images/ai_1.png"/> ?

Comment: "I should move the images folder into the static folder" — Yes

Comment: "Thanks Quentin! So I should move the images folder into the static folder and
change the relative path to" — The URL has to go from whatever the URL of the generated HTML document is. It's usual to use an *absolute* path `/static/images/etc` so it doesn't matter where the HTML document is.